# Can we Add the multiple entity in Android

Tags: android

I want to the send the parameter, header, body. I have set the header field values in header and parameter values in the parameter but I have to send the body also. Body dont have field name just like parameter So I'm doing like below. Please help me is this correct. If not guide me how to do this.

```
httppost.addHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httppost.addHeader("apikey", "");

String JSON = "{\"head\" : {\"version\" : \"1.1\",\"serial\" : \"1008545\",\"skinId\" : \"d381b028-04c2-383d-a9bc-c2a4da412927\",\"storable\" : \"true\",\"validUntil\" : {\"value\" : \"2013/12/31 23:59\",\"format\" : \"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm\"}, \"keywords\":[\"Vistaprint\", \"40% Off Everything\"]},\n\"view\" : [{\"id\" : \"ABSTRACT_VALUE1\",\"text\" : {\"value\" : \"40% Off Everything now only ?9.99\"},\"barcode\" : {\"value\" : \"520851\",\"type\" : \"EAN_13\",\"caption\" : \"520851\"}}],\n\"alerts\" : [{\"id\" : \"ALERT1\",\"geofence\" : {\"value\" : \"1 Temple Avenue, Barnet, London, N20 6TL\",\"latitude\" : \"53.34535\",\"longitude\" : \"-1.34522\",\"rangeinmeter\" : \"200\"}}] }";
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(JSON.toString());

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices", "devices"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regis", "register"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serialNumber", "635133848033113243"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Http Post contains following 

1. Parameters (query parameters) - these parameter will be sent in url, while 
   building url  itself after the complete url path first query parameter will 
   be added with question mark symbol (?) after that all with ampersand (&). Query
   parameters are nothing but name value pairs. These name values pairs can be seen.
2. Headers -  header fields are components of the message header of requests and 
   responses in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol. They define the operating 
   parameters of an HTTP transaction.
3. Body - body again name value pairs present in the form. but this will shown in 
   url. These parameter will be encoded in the post request.

// so with this. as ur question ur parameters ur not sneding, ur sending headers 
  // and body. now instead of setting entity twice. use following code.
 String JSON_data = "{\"head\" : {\"version\" : \"1.1\",\"serial\" : \"1008545\",\"skinId\"   : \"d381b028-04c2-383d-a9bc-c2a4da412927\",\"storable\" : \"true\",\"validUntil\" : {\"value\" : \"2013/12/31 23:59\",\"format\" : \"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm\"}, \"keywords\":[\"Vistaprint\", \"40% Off Everything\"]},\n\"view\" : [{\"id\" : \"ABSTRACT_VALUE1\",\"text\" : {\"value\" : \"40% Off Everything now only ?9.99\"},\"barcode\" : {\"value\" : \"520851\",\"type\" : \"EAN_13\",\"caption\" : \"520851\"}}],\n\"alerts\" : [{\"id\" : \"ALERT1\",\"geofence\" : {\"value\" : \"1 Temple Avenue, Barnet, London, N20 6TL\",\"latitude\" : \"53.34535\",\"longitude\" : \"-1.34522\",\"rangeinmeter\" : \"200\"}}] }";

 // commment this line
 //StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(JSON.toString());

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices", "devices"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regis", "register"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serialNumber", "635133848033113243"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data",JSON_data));

 // still better way create json object like below

JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    object.put("name1","value1");
                    object.put("name2","value2");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }


  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json_data",object .toString));

 // on the server side look for json_data parameter to read the values



 // you can achieve it by using httpurl connection also

 String JSON_data = "{\"head\" : {\"version\" : \"1.1\",\"serial\" : \"1008545\",\"skinId\"   : \"d381b028-04c2-383d-a9bc-c2a4da412927\",\"storable\" : \"true\",\"validUntil\" : {\"value\" : \"2013/12/31 23:59\",\"format\" : \"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm\"}, \"keywords\":[\"Vistaprint\", \"40% Off Everything\"]},\n\"view\" : [{\"id\" : \"ABSTRACT_VALUE1\",\"text\" : {\"value\" : \"40% Off Everything now only ?9.99\"},\"barcode\" : {\"value\" : \"520851\",\"type\" : \"EAN_13\",\"caption\" : \"520851\"}}],\n\"alerts\" : [{\"id\" : \"ALERT1\",\"geofence\" : {\"value\" : \"1 Temple Avenue, Barnet, London, N20 6TL\",\"latitude\" : \"53.34535\",\"longitude\" : \"-1.34522\",\"rangeinmeter\" : \"200\"}}] }";
  // formentity here
 UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp); 
 URL url = new URL(str_url);
 HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
 conection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);            
 conection.connect();

OutputStream output = null;
 try {
 output = conection.getOutputStream();    
 formEntity.writeTo(output);
 output.write(JSON_data.getBytes());

 }   finally  {
  if (output != null) try {   output.close(); } catch (IOException ioe) {}
  }
```

Comment: You gave the body json field name `json_data` but in my case there is no field. I need to sent directly without any name. How can i do this?